# where should I store images of my e-commerce react app?

Tags: reactjs

I have an e-commerce react app, so as you know every product has at least three or four images, so to show the image of product in my website i created a folder with a name of " images " inside the public folder so everytime i want to show images of a specific product i can get and show them very simply and for Now this is very very awesome.
**The Problem**:
as we know each e-commerce website should have an **admin** where he can publish new products and upload new images, so by the time may be i will have thousands of images in my website.
**Question**
what is the best practice to store images of my react app ?
do i need to use third party like AWS or Firebase ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing images in the code-base assets folder is not the best option for large number of images. Handling updates, inserts is a big problem. So you have the following options.

**Options: Cloud/On Premises**

- You may store in the cloud like AWS S3
- If you want to store on premises, you may store in MongoDB Grids
  or even on the File System with file-path stored in the database.

**Step Ahead**

But going ahead you might need responsive images according to the image placeholder. Example for an image you might need thumbnails of different sizes lets say for listing pages, android apps, iOS apps.You might also need to compress the images in case they are heavy for web purpose.

- In that case you may choose to store the images in the desired
  resolutions.For this you'll have to store multiple versions on an image. For  example  product1/original.jpg, product1/compressed.jpg, product1/300x300.jpg etc
- You may resize/crop the images on the fly. If you want to write your resizing systems you may write ImageMagick/vips/PIL etc based code.You may try to search for readymade nginx based plugins to server responsive images.
- If you do not want to do this resizing stuff yourself you may use image storage services like imgix,cloudinary,akamai that provides CDN + image manipulations.Some of these provide storage+manipulation while some only manipulation.

Comment: Hey Holy_driver thank you so much, I'm agree with you.